# Can we add custom objects in BG96 LwM2M implementation?

Tags: c, protocols, m2m, quectel, lwm2m

We have successfully created a client using the LwM2M implementation on BG96 device.

According to the documentation the following LwM2M objects are implemented:

1. Security object
2. Server object
3. Access control object
4. Device object
5. Connectivity monitoring object
6. Location object
7. Connectivity statistics object
8. Firmware update object
9. Software management object
10. Device capability management object

These objects send the data to server in their own constraint environment. The AT commands that are given in documentation are used to configure the files that helps us to deploy a client on our device.

Now the problem that we are facing is that we want to send our own custom next to the server e.g. the values of a sensor. There isn’t any AT command present which can send our sensor values through LwM2M, nor can we edit or create our own lwM2M object that can fulfill this functionality.

In simpler words the LwM2M objects mentioned above transmit their own specific data but we are unable to find a way to send our own custom text/sensor values to the server using LwM2M protocol.

How can we add new resources in the client for customization?

Comment: You seem to have hit quite a specific topic there. Consider helping more people into the discussion by e.g. linking documentation. Maybe giving a short summary of the field, with some prominent keywords, could attract people who happen to how knowhow.

Comment: I think you are not actually off-topic, just in a narrow field. Nevertheless, taking the [tour] could serve as a good luck charm. StackOverflow users can tell when you did and usually appreciate it. You might also double check [help/on-topic] and try to match as much as possible.

Comment: The PS could give the impression of being a second question (and asking more than one could get you close-votes for being too broad). Try to avoid that impression and rephrase to make it more obviously part or detail of the one question you are asking (which I think it is, just make it more obvious).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The stock firmware of BG96 does not support lwM2M custom objects. To use custom objects you need to use BG96 QuesOpen solution.